# Logic Apps, How to Trasform JSON array using Liquid

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-logic-apps

I have an JSON array that is output from a "Get rows" SQL action. I understand how to work with Liquid templates to create a loop so that I can create a new array, but I'm unclear on how to refer to the output from the SQL action in the liquid template. How can I gain access to the array inside my template, i.e. what do I replace "SQL_OUTPUT" with?

```
[
{% for qb_value in SQL_OUTPUT %}
{
      "6": {
        "value": "{{qb_value.First_x0020_Name}}"
      },
      "7": {
        "value": "{{qb_value.Last_x0020_Name}}"
      },
      "8": {
        "value": "{{qb_value.E_x0020_Mail}}"
    }
},
{% endfor %}
]
```

Comment: Hi Erich, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have problem, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I needed to replace "SQL_OUTPUT" with "content"

Comment: @HuryShen Any reason why I shouldn't just use the json(xmlString) instead of liquid template map?

Comment: @Mocas I believe because the requirement was for a transform of data that was already in JSON form, not a data type conversion of XML to JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem, I can provide a sample below for your reference.

**1.** I created a sql table, the data of the table show as blow:

[image]

**2.** Use "Get rows(V2)" action to get the table rows.

[image]

Running the logic app, we can get the rows of the table like below:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://logic-apis-eastasia.azure-apim.net/apim/sql/xxxxxxxxxxx/$metadata#datasets('default%2Cdefault')/tables('%5Bdbo%5D.%5BPerson%5D')/items",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "hury",
      "id": 4
    },
    {
      "@odata.etag": "",
      "ItemInternalId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "name": "john",
      "id": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Please pay attention to the data under `value` field, we need to use it to generate json schema in the next step.

**3.** Then we need to use "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action to parse the value(rows) we got from the table. Please put the `value` from "Get rows(V2)" into the "Content" box of "Parse JSON".

[image]

Then click "**Use sample payload to generate schema**", input the data of `value` field to the box. Click "**Done**", it will generate the json schema automatically.

[image]

**4.** Now, add a "Transform JSON to JSON" action. Choose the `Body` from "Parse JSON" and put it into the "Content" box. The `Body` refers to the data of `value` in my sql data(rows).

[image]

My liquid template is:

```
[
    {% for item in content %}
        {
            "name": "{{item.name}}"
        },
    {% endfor %}
]
```

The `content` in the liquid template refers to the `Body` above(also refers to the data array under the `value` field).

**5.** After running the logic app, we can get the result as expected.

[image]